# How to obtain data from an external web page with curl through POST requests

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, http-headers, php-curl

I have previously made a code that allows me to make an inquiry to an external web page where I sent by GET the id and it shows me the name and surname of a person. That code works very well, is this:

```
      function nome($id)

        {

        $url = 'https://www.dateas.com/es/consulta_cuit_cuil?name=&cuit='.$id;



        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Accept-Lenguage: es-es,es"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

         preg_match_all('/<tr class="odd"><td><a href="(.*?)">/',$html ,$matches);

         if (count($matches[1]) == 0) 
         {
            $result = "Error in the server";
         }
         else if(count($matches[1]) == 1)
         {
            $result = $matches[1][0];
            $result = str_replace('/es/persona/','', $result);
            $result = substr($result, 0,-12);
            $result = str_replace('-', ' ', $result);
            $result = ucwords($result);
         }
        return $result; 
            }

    $Name = nome($_GET['id']);
    echo "<br><br>The name of the person is : ". $Name;
```

This code works well but now I need to extract this information from another website, but to do so I must log in first on that web page and then go to the query section and enter the id, click on the search button and then the page returns the information of the person. The website does not make requests by GET but by POST, to search and display the information of a person.

My problem is that I do not know how to extract the information in this new page because I must first login and then look for the person entering their id but the requests are handled by POST.

How could I get the information of the person making the query through CURL or any other PHP method?

this is the page where is the login form to enter the web where the query is made: http://buscardatos.com/Socios/ingresso.php

After logging in, we should go to: http://www.buscardatos.com/Personas/DNI

there is a text field where the id is entered and by clicking on the search button the information of the person is displayed.

the website makes the request by POST. I have tried to use the same code that I have shown here but it throws me an error of "page not found".

Could you please help me with some code or information about how to solve this issue?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at trying to do this yourself, use tools to capture data when you send the login request so that you can try and replicate it via PHP Curl.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to capture the interaction between your local port and the server with a capture tool (such as Fiddler. In fact, the browser itself can see this information).

First, you need to use a browser to complete the login and query process, and then you can clearly see the http/https data information that the browser interacts with the server.

Next, you need to use PHP code to simulate the browser to submit the login information like the server, and then get the data returned by the server (this data may be a session value, generally stored locally in the browser's cookie.)

Next you can use the CURL above to get the data. Remember to bring the data needed for server verification. If it is a cookie, maybe you can add it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,'cookie= XXXX ; cookie_type= YYYY;');
```

As long as you provide the correct data and URL, you can get the data you want.